# Should I map cascade operations in hibernate when it's fully mapped in SGBD?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, foreign-keys, cascade

I've defined all foreign keys and cascade operations in MySQL, should I also map then in hibernate objects or leave MySQL do it's things alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to define them within your DB then defining them on your Hibernate objects really will just generate extra delete statements that really aren't necessary.

Personally I think that having cascading deletes within a DB can be very difficult to work with as your DB has more of the *intelligence* of your application.  I prefer to define these types of business rules within code rather than in the DB because it keeps all of your persistence information in one place.  I think it's a similar argument as to why many people dislike DB triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You can define in hibernate but it's not necessary.

You have to use mapping for defining relationship in hibernate that is in one of following way
1. one to many
2. one to one
3. many to one
4. many to many

And all other things hibernate will handle.

Use hibernate.cfg.xml file for configureation.